# Are there any magical items that would have an adverse effect if you had a negative Con?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, ability-scores

I was just reviewing my Q&A about the [effect of a negative Constitution modifier](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/96489/how-can-a-negative-con-stat-affect-my-character-development), and that is limited to the effects on the PC stats and abilities (specifically HP, fatigue, etc).

I remembered that Barbarians also use Con for the their Unarmored Defense ability, and (while it is a UA, so probably not as important, but still note-worthy in this regard) The Giant Soul Sorcerous Origin relies on Con as well.

Are there any Magic Items that would be affected by a negative Constitution Modifier?

Answer (score 5):

There are many items that have various effects tied to your constitution modifier. I have chosen only to list those items for which a negative constitution modifier creates a serious malfunction.

#### Ring of Temporal Salvation

> If you die while wearing this gray crystal ring, you vanish and reappear in an unoccupied space within 5 feet of the space you left (or the nearest unoccupied space). You have a number of hit points equal to 3d6 + your Constitution modifier. If your hit point maximum is lower than the number of hit points you regain, your hit point maximum rises to a similar amount. If you have any levels of exhaustion, reduce your level of exhaustion by 1. Once the ring is used, it turns to dust and is destroyed.

A negative constitution modifier can nullify the effects of this magic item entirely. With a modifier of -3 or lower, rolling three 1s on the 3d6 means you reappear unconscious.

#### Soul Coin

> A non-evil creature can carry a number of soul coins equal to or less than its Constitution modifier without penalty. A non-evil creature carrying a number of soul coins greater than its Constitution modifier has disadvantage on its attack rolls, ability checks, and saving throws.

With a constitution modifier less than or equal to 0, a single soul coin imposes disadvantage on all attack rolls, ability checks, and saving throws.

Comment: While a negative Con mod is certainly disadvantageous when carrying _Soul Coins_, in that carrying even one imposes a penalty, I would not say it is a 'serious malfunction'.  Indeed, hindering non-evil creatures seems like one of the functions of a _soul coin_.  This is in contrast to the _ring of temporal salvation_ where, as you point out, a negative Con mod can prevent the _ring_ from doing what it is designed to do.  Both items are certainly responses to the OP's search for items that "would be affected by a" negative Con mod.

Comment: I guess for the soul coins it's a matter of perspective. Disadvantage every time you role the d20 feels like a serious malfunction to me, at least from the perspective of the good character.